# Examples of cryptographic methods using outside randomness

Tags: cryptography, pseudo-random-generators

Most cryptographic protocols like pseudorandom number generators run only on "internal" information: that is you set a seed and the next state is a function of its previous state etc..  I am wondering if there are any examples of cryptographic protocols that make use of "external" randomness or information, which is assumed to be known by an adversary?  For example is there a PRNG or block cipher that has some "injection step" where it pulls in some public source of information to assist in the encryption?

The only example I can come up with is an IV for AES.

Comment: Are you not confusing terms? PRNG to be secure the need the internal states to be kept secret. AES needs modes of operation and for probabilistic encryption, we need an IV and this IV must be unpredictable for CBC mode, and for CTR the (key,IV) pair must not be used more than one...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [salt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)) or [IV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization_vector) or [nonce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_nonce) or [public key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography) all meet your requirements.